# Orbit slider doesn't work in WordPress with Foundation

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation, orbit

I installed the Foundation theme for WordPress and it's pretty straight forward, same as a normal static site except for one problem. I added the Orbit slider (I know it's deprecated, but I need it and it works fine). Now, normally I would add,

```
<script>
$(document).foundation({
    orbit: {
        animation: 'slide'
    }
});
</script>
```

to the end of a page, and I've tried placing it in the `footer.php` file just before the closing tag, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Link for the theme is here: http://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/

Comment: Do you have a public test URL to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all JavaScript & CSS dependencies for Orbit slider.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have the following in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

then control the slider using something like:

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="navigation_arrows: false; bullets: false; animation_spreed: 1; timer_speed: 5000; slide_number: false; pause_on_hover: true; resume_on_mouseout: false,">
<li><img src="example1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="example2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="example3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally have my Foundation call inside of a bigger JS file. Wordpress uses no-conflict for jQuery so you'll have issues with the "$". Set it up like this instead:

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
      $(document).foundation({
          orbit: {
            animation: 'slide'
          }
      });
    });`